# SQL Server High Availability mode When I failover the node Permissions are going away

Tags: sql-server, high-availability

I created an Availability group with 2 Servers. When I fail over from one node to another the permissions are going away. (I granted a SQL server login DBO permissions)

So what I did was I wanted the remap permissions script to be run every time AG-Role change alert happens
If I run the Job manually after the role change permissions are working.
But Job is not running automatically everytime role change happens. It is failing with below error message

Unable to access availability database 'TestDB' because the database replica is not in the PRIMARY or SECONDARY role. Connections to an availability database is permitted only when the database replica is in the PRIMARY or SECONDARY role. Try the operation again later. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 983).  The step failed.

Is there any better way to handle the permissions issue when switching nodes in HA? How to fix the above error?

Comment: Likely the SIDs on your logins don't match. https://sqlsunday.com/2016/10/11/how-to-sync-logins-between-availability-group-replicas/

Comment: Yes. Worked like a charm, Thank you.